# Physics Velocity Correction

Tags: physics, graphing-functions

So, been up all night working on getting the velocity/angle of arrow simulations perfect. Running into an issue with the physics engine I'm using is ever so slightly off (probably a rounding issue)

The Velocity is a fixed 55 "Units"

Correction Required at ranges (Range being the variable):

```
Range | Correction
30      0.0180
100     0.0055
200     0.0027
300     0.00165
```

After applying manual corrections on the velocity, I've been able to come up with the above data set.

Would anyone be so kind as to help me figure out a formula which satisfies the above problem?

**Minor Background Information**

The formulas I am using for the base calculations are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile

Comment: You could try to make your time-steps $dt$ smaller to give a better resolution. But perhaps the most practical solution is to obtain more data and make a fit.

Comment: I can supply more data points, but formulating equations has never been my strong suite. That's why after 17hours of straight programming I have to admit defeat and ask for help

Comment: Using an in-built fit function in some software you can get your hands on doesn't require any formulation of eq.s.

Comment: Also, these corrections are on the order of 0.005 % or lower of the expected value. This really isn't a problem, especially since these corrections get *lower* with distance - it would be another thing if there were some error that built up over time. But really, I think your simulation is doing just fine without any correction whatsoever.

Comment: The arrows are missing the target by ~40cm over 300 meters, this unfortunately is not "doing fine" :) This is a 0.0013 miscalculation but it is enough for the users to notice it, sadly

Comment: All right, either way, I don't think anyone is able to make a model of the error of your script (at least without detailed knowledge of it), so I'd make the fit and write this correction into the calculation.

Comment: Could you provide more data points ? If you prefer, you can e-mail them to me (my address is in my profile). If you cannot get a better resolution, a curve fit of the correction is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Frentos's answer, for the time being, let us assume something like $$y=\frac ax+b$$ Using your values, a simple linear regression gives $$y=\frac{0.541976}{x}-0.000038024$$ which gives as predicted corrections $0.01803$, $0.00538$, $0.00267$, $0.00177$.

As said, with more data points, something better could come out.

**Edit**

Take care; the constant term is not significant. So, $y=\frac{0.540401}{x}$ seems to more than sufficient (predicted values $0.01801$, $0.00540$, $0.00270$, $0.00180$)

Comment: After moddifying it ever so slightly it came to be
$$y=\frac{0.541976}{x}-0.000149024024$$

With these magic numbers, at 30m it misses by 2mm and 300m it misses by 9mm, which is very much acceptable, Thank you for the pointers

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, it's difficult to make a model of the error without more knowledge of the your script.

The first three data points fit an almost perfect inverse relationship:

```
 30 * 0.0180  = 0.54
100 * 0.0055  = 0.55
200 * 0.0027  = 0.54
300 * 0.00165 = 0.495
```

The fact that the $300$ range datapoint doesn't fit suggests something more complex is going on, but without more information about the script or more datapoints it's hard to come up with anything substantial.